# Trouble rendering dynamic geom_hlines in Power BI with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

I'm attempting to create a ggplot2 object in power bi that will render any number of horizontal lines depending on measures dropped in and out of the "Values" bin. I thought I'd do this with a for loop that adds an additional geom_hline to the object depending on the length of the dataframe. I also want each line to have a different color, and the value of the hline to render with the label in the legend.

The dataframe I am using has 3 static columns titled - Year, Escalation, and Type. Any additional columns beyond the first 3 would be considered data to be used for the horizontal lines.

This is what I have so far...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

# create a unique color set
n <- 60
qual_col_pals = brewer.pal.info[brewer.pal.info$category == 'qual',]
col_vector = unlist(mapply(brewer.pal, qual_col_pals$maxcolors, rownames(qual_col_pals)))

# create an dynamic x axis label depending on the number of years to be plotted

scale <- if(length(dataset$Year) < 30) {
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(dataset$Year), max(dataset$Year)))
} else if (length(dataset$Year) >= 30  & length(dataset$Year) <= 60) {
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(dataset$Year), max(dataset$Year), by = 2))    
} else {
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(dataset$Year), max(dataset$Year), by = 5))
}

#ggplot object

plot <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Year, y = Escalation)) +

        geom_point(aes(color = "#094780"), size = 3) +

        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(dataset$Escalation), color = col_vector[1]), linetype = "dashed") +

        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median(dataset$Escalation), color = col_vector[2]), linetype = "dashed") +

        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "#942832")) +
        theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "#942832")) + 

        scale +

        scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dataset$Escalation), max(dataset$Escalation), by = 0.02),2))

# add horizontal comparison lines

addline <- function(data){
        c <- list(unlist(unique(dataset[3])), paste("Mean ", round(mean(dataset$Escalation), 3)), paste("Median", round(median(dataset$Escalation),3)))
        t <- list("#094780", col_vector[1], col_vector[2])
        for (i in 1:data){
                line = geom_hline(aes(yintercept = dataset[1,3+i], color = col_vector[2+i]))

                plot = plot + line

                c[3+i] = paste(unlist(names(dataset)[3+i]), " Escalation :", round(dataset[1 ,3+i], 3))
                t[3+i] = col_vector[2+i]
        }

    m = scale_color_manual(name = "", values = t, labels = c)

    plot = plot + m

    return(plot)
}

addline(NCOL(dataset)-3)
```

It's rendering, but its not giving me what I'm expecting when I add data for more than 1 horizontal line (its shifting the line with the data but not properly naming it or coloring it). For reference, if there were 2 horizontal lines and it were hardcoded, I would want the code to look like this (this renders correctly in power BI).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

n <- 60
qual_col_pals = brewer.pal.info[brewer.pal.info$category == 'qual',]
col_vector = unlist(mapply(brewer.pal, qual_col_pals$maxcolors, rownames(qual_col_pals)))

scale <- if(length(dataset$Year) < 30) {
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(dataset$Year), max(dataset$Year)))
} else if (length(dataset$Year) >= 30  & length(dataset$Year) <= 60) {
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(dataset$Year), max(dataset$Year), by = 2))    
} else {
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(dataset$Year), max(dataset$Year), by = 5))
}

plot <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Year, y = Escalation)) +

        geom_point(aes(color = "#094780"), size = 3) +

        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(dataset$Escalation), color = col_vector[1]), linetype = "dashed") +

        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median(dataset$Escalation), color = col_vector[2]), linetype = "dashed") +

        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "#942832")) +
        theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "#942832")) + 

        scale +

        scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dataset$Escalation), max(dataset$Escalation), by = 0.02),2)) +

        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = dataset[1,4], color = col_vector[3]),) +

        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = dataset[1,5], color = col_vector[4]),) +

        scale_color_manual(
                name = "", 
                values = list("#094780", col_vector[1], col_vector[2], col_vector[3], col_vector[4]), 
                labels = list(unlist(unique(dataset[3])), 
                        paste("Mean ", round(mean(dataset$Escalation), 3)), 
                        paste("Median", round(median(dataset$Escalation),3)), 
                        paste(unlist(names(dataset)[4]), " Escalation :", round(dataset[1 ,4], 3)), 
                        paste(unlist(names(dataset)[5]), " Escalation :", round(dataset[1 ,5], 3))
                )
        )

plot
```

I'm still a novice when it comes to coding, so I'm pretty sure I'm just not understanding something basic about how the loop works.

I know this is a bit to shift through, but I'm having a hard time really debugging because I'd have to export the data set from power BI into r studio. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for supplying your full code, but it's hard to figure out what's going on without some workable data.  Even if you cannot share a real dataset, can you share an example dataset that would work to show the issue clearly here?  If possible, please share an example of one of your `datasets` (or a sample of it) via `dput(dataset)` or `dput(dataset[sample(1:nrow(dataset), X),])`, where `X` is the number of observations you want to sample.

Comment: @chemdork123 thanks for the reply. Heres an example with 3 measures output as columns meant to rendered as reference lines. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/147W6O4trW3sMKCF26cM_1KGPPOtE1OjR/view?usp=sharing